# Visual Studio DLL reference dependencies

Tags: visual-studio

I'm new to the world of .NET and I'm trying to understand the build process. If the concept of DLLs is to resolve references at run time why does visual studio need to to know about DLLs at compile time in order to build an executable ?  Can't seem to find a definitive answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

DLLs are loaded at runtime so your code can call code in that DLL, indeed. However, they are also needed at compile time so you can write code calling into that library.

Back in C++ I think that was done with `.lib` files or via COM, so the compiler didn't actually need the DLL. In .NET that's different because the DLL contains the code to run and the interface so other programs can use it.